# SQL Union overhead

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, union

Im having a performance issue on using union.
I have two sql queries with same column results but from different tables:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
FROM TABLE1
```

(which takes about 4 secs to finish) and:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
FROM TABLE2 INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON ID
```

which also takes about 4 secs to finish. When I use `UNION ALL` for the two queries the result takes 22 seconds to finish.

Any suggestions to improve performance?

Comment: Use UNION ALL if you do not distinct values across result sets.

Comment: @nikola sorry, actually the result was from a UNION ALL

Comment: @AaronDigulla sql server 2008

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović there are no ORDER BY clauses. there are WHERE clauses though.

Comment: Could you please post the query?

Answer (score 2):

UNION clause removes duplicates by using DISTINCT on the select clause and creating some temporary tables and those are permformance expensive tasks. Do you need those duplicates or not?

Check [this link by Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/) it has a detailed analysis on using UNION and UNION ALL, with execution plans analysis too.

I would check too if indexes are correctly used on these select clauses, without a detailed view of tables structures is hard to say.

Comment: I was answering as he was commenting, that is why I didn't saw his comment.

Comment: Thanks. but my question is not really whether to use UNION or UNION ALL but whether to use UNION or another workaround like creating a stored procedure that runs the two queries separately and returning one table containing the results.

Comment: Then you must rewrite the question as how it is posted, at least on my opinion, you're asking to improve performance using UNION. In that case you can try to use OR clause, [check this MSDN link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/f21ebb64-f470-4d9a-9c3a-cb08b2ac52a3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `UNION ALL` - it avoids finding duplicates. It is a good practice not to use `UNION` without `ALL` and `DISTINCT`, except you really need it.

Comment: He used UNION ALL(look in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

As always with performance questions: Measure.

So the next step would be to get the execution plan from your database and look at that. Open a new question if you don't understand the plan.